# Something goes wrong after jQuery triggered

Tags: jquery

My problem is same as the subject but I don't really know how to describe it, so I've put onto Youtube. It's a video of less than 1 minute.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ESvnK5VsUn8

Both of the tabs got no jQuery to do with. It's just:

```
<a href='path'><button>TAB A</button></a>
<a href='path'><button>TAB B</button></a>
```

The paths are fine.

As there are many codes so I decide not to post the codes here.

Do you know what the problem can be?

For testing purpose, I've changed the "Logout" tab into Yahoo and linking to yahoo.com.

https://jsfiddle.net/hdd40g7r/2/

After clicking "click here to hide your info"(with jQuery), then the tabs on the top right hand corner don't work anymore.

Thanks a lot,

Kenny

Comment: *"I decide not to post the codes here"* .... well without a [mcve] not much anyone here can do to help

Comment: Have you checked the console? If any error occurs in the first triggering then the rest of jquery code will not work. Also use console.log() to keep a log in which part the error is being occurred.

Comment: Thanks charlietfl and arsho, I've put the codes on JS Fiddle, hope it helps. And arsho, I did checked the console, but no error reports. Thanks again.    https://jsfiddle.net/hdd40g7r/2/

Comment: I've voted to close this because it's insanely impossible to determine what you're asking.  "Something goes wrong"???  You couldn't walk into a doctor's office and tell the staff "something is wrong", and don't expect us to be mind readers for you here.

Comment: `insanely impossible` are not even good for variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element with id "topintro" is too big and covers your nav bar.

The buttons are working but you can't click them because are under an other element (the #topintro).

You can make it smaller or use css to send it behind the nav bar

```
#topintro {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Using the sellect tool in your browser's webtools is an easy way to see the problem.

Comment: Thank you very very much Thanasis! Have a nice day.

Comment: Sorry Thanasis, one more question, you mentioned 'select tool', is that a feature on I.E.? Coz I didn't see that on Chrome. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, personaly I use only Google Chrome and Firefox for web development. On both of them, F12 opens the webtools and there is a select tool "inspect element". You can also access it by right clicking the element and selecting inspect element. IE has it too.